# Is there any configuration can force initalize the NumPy module during import pytorch?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I have things like

```
python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/transformer.py:20: UserWarning: Failed to initialize NumPy: module compiled against API version 0x10 but this version of numpy is 0xf (Triggered internally at ../torch/csrc/utils/tensor_numpy.cpp:84.)
```

But I definitely need the numpy thus I need the API version to match, so I do not want this just be a Warning, I want it to be an error. I do **not** want manually detect the NumPy version, because both pytorch and numpy version can vary. And different numpy can share same API version. It should only error out when the API mismatched.

Preferably I also want to fail or install new numpy at the pip level if the current installed numpy is too old. Is there any way to do this instead of manually hard code numpy==xxx at pip command line?

**update**
It seems I can use `warnings.filterwarnings("error", category=UserWarning, message=warning_pattern)`  as early as possible (before any pytorch importing) to convert he warning into error.

However, it looks like there is no way to for the numpy update to compatible version during pip yet.

Answer (score -1):

One can explicitly check a version (of any module) like this:

```py
import numpy as np


v = np.__version__
if v != "1.26.1":
    print('wrong version')
else:
    print('correct version:', v)
```

And returns this:

```
correct version: 1.26.1
```

or you can **explicitly raise an error** like this:

```py
v = np.__version__
if v == "1.26.2":
    print('correct numpy version:', v)
else:
    raise Exception(f'wrong numpy version: {v}')
```

The alternative to the above is a `requirements.txt` file in a standalone python package (virtual environment).

finally, you can invoke an instalation of a specific version like this:

```py
import subprocess
import sys

subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'numpy==1.26.1'])
```

Comment: as I described I do not want to explicitly specify the numpy version, because it varies when pytorch upgrade its API.

Comment: @Wang, thanks for the clarity in the comment. i have extended the answer to accommodate for this too.